# Drupal 8 Add multipal fields (fields group) with single click on "add another item"

Tags: drupal-8

I want to add 3 fields group (Title, Detail and Image) which can repeat unlimited time so I have added 3 fields from Drupal 8 Admin panel:
Home >> Administration >> Structure >> Content types >> Article >> Manage fields

But i need a facility to add all 3 fields by clicking on add another item. As of now all these 3 fields have its own add another item button.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [Drupal paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module for this. You create a paragraph type with the 3 fields and allow users to create multiple paragraphs. I use this extensively for doing exactly what you are wanting to do.